# Instantiating class inside a ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-viewmodel

This app creates a greeting card. Flow is select a photo on fragment #1, a contact on fragment #2, enter a message on fragment #3 and review, confirm and send on fragment #4.

The data for this app is stored in SQLite (using Room).

Current state has the data being shared between fragments using a combination of bundles/arguments and saving to SQLite. It's messy.

Future state is put all the data for these fragments into the existing ViewModel so that all the data is available in all the fragments (then save to SQLite once the card is completed).

I want to use the same class that the SQLite structure is based on in the ViewModel - basically, instantiate it whenever the ViewModel is called. This is the class:

```
class DBClasses {

    @Entity(tableName="photos")
    data class photos(

        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
        val user_id: String,

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val photo_id: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "photo_name")
        val photo_name: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "upload_date")
        val upload_date: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
        val status: String

    )

    @Entity(tableName="cards")
    data class postcards(

        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
        val user_id: String,

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val postcard_id: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "photo_id")
        val photo_id: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
        val status: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "message_id")
        val message_id: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "contact_id")
        val contact_id: Int

    )


    @Entity(tableName="contacts")
    data class contacts(

        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
        val user_id: String,

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val contact_id: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
        val status: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "addressee")
        val addressee: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
        var first_name: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
        val last_name: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
        var address: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
        val city: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "state")
        val state: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "zip_code")
        val zip_code: String

    )

    @Entity(tableName="messages")
    data class messages(

        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
        val user_id: String,

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val message_id: Long,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
        val status: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
        val message: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "string")
        val string: String,

    )

    @Entity(tableName = "owner")
    data class owner(

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val owner_id: Long,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
        val user_id: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
        val status: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "sender")
        val sender: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
        val first_name: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
        val last_name: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
        val address: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
        val city: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "state")
        val state: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "zip_code")
        val zip_code: String

    )


}
```

Is there a way to do this? Otherwise I think I have to basically recreate the class in the ViewModel which seems like unnecessary duplication. I tried to instantiate the existing class (DBClasses) in the ViewModel, which allowed me to do it, but I get errors when I try to actually reference the empty values in the fragments.

EDIT:
To get access to the values I took an alternative approach setting this up in the ViewModel - see below for an example of contacts:

```
private val _user_id = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val user_id: LiveData<String> = _user_id

    private val _contact_id = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val contact_id: LiveData<Int> = _contact_id

    private val _status = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val status: LiveData<String> = _status

    private val _addressee = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val addressee: LiveData<String> = _addressee

    private val _first_name = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val first_name: LiveData<String> = _first_name

    private val _last_name = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val last_name: LiveData<String> = _last_name

    private val _address = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val address: LiveData<String> = _address

    private val _city = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val city: LiveData<String> = _city

    private val _state = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val state: LiveData<String> = _state

    private val _zip_code = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val zip_code: LiveData<String> = _zip_code

    fun setUserID(user_id: String) {
        _user_id.value = user_id
    }

    fun setStatus(status: String) {
        _status.value = status
    }

    fun setAddressee(addressee: String) {
        _addressee.value = addressee
    }

    fun setFirstName(first_name: String) {
        _first_name.value = first_name
    }

    fun setLastName(last_name: String) {
        _last_name.value = last_name
    }

    fun setAddress(address: String) {
        _address.value = address
    }

    fun setCity(city: String) {
        _city.value = city
    }

    fun setState(state: String) {
        _state.value = state
    }

    fun setZip(zip_code: String) {
        _zip_code.value = zip_code
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer `DbClasses` class? Did you mean to make it an `object` and use it only as a name prefix for your Entity classes? What errors do you get? Can you show the code that produces errors?

Comment: @Tenfour04 DBClasses is basically a container that holds all the Room database (SQLite) tables used by the app. It is reference frequently in the repository and DAO. I don't recall the exact error but it said you can't call an empty value. I deleted all that and added the code I just included in the edit of the main description. Sorry I don't have more helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one view model in the activity level by initializing the view model using `by activityViewModels()`. This view model will hold the existing state even though your Fragment is changing.

Your can also combine it with each of the fragment view model if you feel that you have a complex state management in your fragments.